# How to remove all newlines from file within a perl script?

Tags: file, perl

I have a file that when viewed with `vi` with `:set list` that looks like the following:

```
one^M$
two$
three$^M
four$
```

I want to remove all the newlines (`$`) in the file from within a perl script. So the file should look like this:

```
one^Mtwothree^Mfour
```

After that I want to replace the CR (`^M`) with newlines (`\n`) but that is another story...

I tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "test.txt";
system("sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' $file");
exit 0;
```

I know it's ugly to use `system` but I am punished with this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
```

Does anyone know an elegant way to achive my goal?

Comment: It would be an understatement to call `perl -e 'system("sed ...` an anti-pattern

Comment: you say you want to remove all new lines, then replace all instances of ^M with \n. Doesnt this make the real requirement to just remove ^M?

Comment: No, if I yust remove the ^M I got four lines but what I want in the end is three lines:
    `one
    twothree
    four`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using Perl it's unnecessary to use sed. Perl has an `-i` switch which makes this sort of thing easy.

```
perl -pi -e's/\n//' test.txt
```

Alternatively [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) provides a functional equivalent to `-i`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;
my $file = shift; # get filename from argument
path($file)->edit_lines(sub { s/\n// });
```

In both cases the substitution will be performed for each line, which should be fine because the line contains its trailing newline. You can perform it on the whole file at once by passing `-0777` to the oneliner, or using `->edit` instead of `->edit_lines`, then you would want to use `s/\n//g` to replace multiple occurrences.

Comment: I solved my second task with `path($file)->edit_lines(sub { s/^M/\n/g });`. But why do I not need the `g` in your substitution?

Comment: The `/g` modifier makes the substitution run for every match instead of just the first one. Since edit_lines runs for every line, you don't need `/g` if you only need it to run once per line. After you remove the newlines though, you only have one line, so you'll need `/g` to affect multiple instances on that line.